# GCP GCE doesn't permit Ingress traffic to a port opened by node port on K8S

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

```
ytong@master:~$ kubectl get service
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP        4h11m
nginx        LoadBalancer   10.111.227.218   <pending>     80:31371/TCP   75m
```

Please ignore the pending status for LoadBalancer.
Since I don't use GKE, but use GCE with K8S installed with kubeadm to create a service in LoadBalancer service, so it will be on PENDING status forever.

```
ytong@master:~$ kubectl get node -o wide
NAME     STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION   CONTAINER-RUNTIME
master   Ready    master   4h12m   v1.18.1   10.2.0.3      <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS   5.0.0-1034-gcp   docker://19.3.6
worker   Ready    <none>   3h41m   v1.18.1   10.2.0.4      <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS   5.0.0-1034-gcp   docker://19.3.6

master  us-central1-f           10.2.0.3 (nic0) 35.222.140.199      
worker  us-central1-f           10.2.0.4 (nic0) 34.67.101.1     

ytong@master:~$ curl http://10.2.0.3:31371
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>

ytong@master:~$ curl http://35.222.140.199:31371
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I can use 31371 port opened by node port to access nginx service finally mapped to port 80 on pod on either GCP GCE VMs or jump server on GCP.

But I can't visit it from my desktop over Internet.

```
ytong@L-AUN-11021501 MINGW64 ~
$ curl http://35.222.140.199:31371
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection was reset
```

I believe the connection to 31371 port is blocked by GCP but I tried to permit all traffic for both default VPC and VPC created by me to hold GCE VMs, it doesn't work.

Continue to update the thread.

I add 2 firewall rules and try to permit tcp:31371 traffic to GCE VMs where k8s node port service running on it.
[image]

Comment: "I tried to permit all traffic for both default VPC and VPC created by me" means, you have created firewall rules to allow ingress traffic from internet?

Comment: I also have a kubeadm cluster setup on top of GCP instances. I just tested and for me it works with no problems. I had to create firewall rules to make it work. So make sure to create a rule like this: `gcloud compute --project=**your-project** firewall-rules create nginx-ingress --direction=INGRESS --priority=1000 --network=default --action=ALLOW --rules=tcp:31371 --source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0 --target-tags=kubeadm`. Don't forget to add a the `kubeadm` network label to your kubeadm instances.

Comment: Let me know if it worked.

Comment: My case is a little different from your description. @mWatney. In my case, I attach two GCE VM with network tag kubeadm to a VPC created by me for lfs258, so that I change your command to specify --network=lfs258. Or do I still need to use default network instead. Is all public IP routed by default network with tag? I try to run ip command on GCE VM and I can't find public external IP seen from GCP GCE console setup on it.

Comment: I add two firewall rules for both lfs258 and default VPC to permit tcp:31371 traffic. But I am still unable to visit service exposed by node port by using public ip for either node to visit like http://public-ip:31371. You may see my added firewall rules in my post.

Comment: Plus, http://public-ip:31371 can be accessed from either GCP jump server or either VM in K8S cluster

Comment: Are you actually sure you're using the network tags in your instances? [Configuring network tags](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags), otherwise, rules won't apply. You can check your iptables in your cluster. There's definitely a firewall and those are the two options that I can think of.